# Jumpy scrolling with mouse wheel

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, mouse-wheel

All of a sudden, when I try scrolling through a web page, for every click of the mouse-wheel, it moves up or down a whole page, not smooth scrolling.

Yesterday it was still scrolling smoothly. What could have caused this and what can I do about it?

**EPILOGUE:** The problem disappeared somewhere after playing with scroll wheel settings, but they were already correct. I think this behaviour was perhaps just Chrome being wobbly.

Comment: It’s an option in your mouse settings. Go to control panel.

Comment: @Appleoddity Yes, it's a setting "Multiple Lines at a time", vs it could be "One screen at a time. It has always been on the former, and still I get this. And only in Chrome.

Comment: Ouch. I stopped all Chrome processes, restarted and it's still the same.

Comment: I had similar problems. Each browser now responded to wheel movement radically differently. There was also a significant response time delay such that the wheel had turned quite a bit before any scrolling had even started. Even adjusting the Additional Mouse options did not resolve the problem. Things were not sorted out until I set System Property Advanced Performance Visual settings to manual and checked every box and then clicked on Apply.  Even then it required a computer reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your mouse wheel settings to make sure switch the number of scroll lines to the default 3 lines as below:

[image]

Comment: not helping in my case, I set it to even 1 line and it still scrolls a whole page.

Answer (score 2):

I have a ms mobile mouse 3500 that runs on its own usb dongle. After trying all sorts of actions, nothing was working. Then I unplugged the dongle and plugged it back in. Scrolling became smooth and no longer jumped multiple lines. Not sure what happened when i reboot because i may have to un-plug the dongle and re-plug each time. I remember with a very old version of ubuntu linux that this was a problem and that's what promptd me to try this with windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel, open devices and printers, click mouse, go to scroll, change the number of lines being scrolled. Mine was to 100 lines, I changed it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the mouse wheel settings doesn't work for you, try these workarounds:

- Re-plug in the mouse (or the USB dongle)
- Plug in another non-identical mouse to allow it to install its driver
  --- as suggested in this thread  [Mouse scrolls too many lines at a time in all applications, changing settings in control panel does not fix](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/mouse-scrolls-too-many-lines-at-a-time-in-all/92926ee2-d3ad-4124-8835-b47dbd43fbad) by DuchessofWorms

(I had this issue with 2 different Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic mouse on 2 different Windows PCs despite having set the correct settings for the number of scroll lines.)